# Java Mail not working in Cloud Server

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-platform, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a Java EE web application which run on GlassFish server. I have written the following code to send emails through the application.
When I test the application in my home PC and Laptop, it send emails immediately. When I run the very same application in a google cloud server, it gives a time out exception. What can be the possible causes?

```
package com.divudi.ejb;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Stateless
public class EmailManagerEjb {

    final static String USERNAME = "mygmailaccount@gmail.com";
    final static String PASSWORD = "mygmailpassword";
    static Session session = null;

    public void sendEmail1(String toEmail, String messageHeading, String messageBody) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        if (session == null) {
            session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                }
            });
        }
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USERNAME));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
            message.setSubject(messageHeading);
            message.setText(messageBody);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Send Successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: From the first section in [Sending Email from an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/): `Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587`.  In short, you can't do it with Gmail.

Comment: You need to [use the version of JavaMail included in Google App Engine, and let it configure the Session for you](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the comment of stdunbar, I created firewall Exceptions for the ports 25, 465 and 587 for google cloud compute engine.

Then everything started working fine.

Now emails are been sent successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using App Engine, you can use [JavaMail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api) which uses the [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/). Alternatively, if you are using Compute Engine, then we recommend that you use another mail service like [Mailgun or Sendgrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use).